# Display custom post types of a certain category only

Tags: wordpress, loops, categories

I have some `faqs` on my site and want to show only faqs under a certain category. The categories include `worker`, `company`, `test`.

Here is my code:

```
$faq = new WP_Query(array(
          'post_type'=>'faq',
          'order' => 'DESC',
          'category_name' => 'test',
        ));
  while($faq->have_posts()) : $faq->the_post();
```

this should be showing me all the posts under the category of test but it is not doing that. I have also tried `cat => (id)` and still no result. The loop is always empty.

Any ideas?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [WP -- Get posts by category?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11909304/wp-get-posts-by-category)

Answer (score 1):

This question has already been answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11909304/wp-get-posts-by-category) and [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/161071/wp-query-by-category-name) but I will summarise the answers applied to your particular case.

The category_name parameter needs to be the slug of the category, and not the category name, you are using:

```
'category_name' => 'test'
```

Does one of your categories have the slug "test"?

Here are other parameters you can use instead:

```
cat (int) - use category id.
category_name (string)- use category slug (NOT name).
category__and (array) - use category id.
category__in (array) - use category id.
category__not_in (array) - use category id.
```

Check your results like this:

```
$faq = new WP_Query(...);    
print_r($faq->posts); die();
```

That will display the list of posts on the screen (for debugging purposes).